# Complete the solution so that the function will break up camel casing, using a space between words

Tags: python

Complete the solution so that the function will break up camel casing, using a space between words.

Example
"camelCasing"  =>  "camel Casing"

What should i do?

Comment: Hat have you tried so far?

Comment: Use what your learned in class... Don't just copy and paste your question here. Your teacher wouldn't have set you a task for something you've not learned. If you are struggling, maybe speak to your teacher for assistance. Once you make a start, if you are still struggling then post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest idea is to just iterate through the string, creating a new one and if current letter is in the 65-90 ascii range (capital letters) add additional space

```
def fun(cc):
   new=""
   for letter in cc:
       if ord(letter) in range(65,91):
           new+=" "
       new+=letter
   return new
```

If you care about speed don't use in range, just compare to lower and upper bound.

Comment: Wouldn't `isupper()` be simpler than checking the ASCII value?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be using regular expressions.

```
import re



def fun(string):
    # Pattern:capture all letters where lowercase letters follow on single uppercase
    # or beginning of a string
    pattern=r"((?:[A-Z]|^[a-z]){1}[a-z]*)"
    # find all matches
    match = re.findall(pattern,string)
    
    # append to single result
    result = ""
    for i in match:
        result += i
        # Space as word divider
        result += " "
    
    return(result)

print(fun("camelCase"))
# camel Case
```